# Concat big arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, optimization

hello I'm having problems when merging big arrays on a react native app, I'm trying to do a infinite scroll on react native, the problem is that when the array is 500+ items of length every time I add more items my js thread freeze for like a second

this is the code that I'm using to merge the state with the new items

`setData(prev => prev.concat(result));`

Which would be the best way to do this?

edit: I'm not Rendering 500 items at same time, I'm using a library called [react-native-large-list](https://github.com/bolan9999/react-native-largelist), that library do all the optimization and recycling of the views behind the scene.

Comment: You could try the spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#a_better_way_to_concatenate_arrays

Comment: The best way to render 500 items is to not render 500 items.

Comment: It's hard to say from your question, but you're probably wasting resources rendering off screen elements. Most apps that use an infinite scroll virtualize off-screen elements. Your app is probably performing badly because you're rendering a large number of dom elements, most of which you don't need to be showing, not because concat is not performant.

Comment: im using a library colled [react-native-large-list](https://github.com/bolan9999/react-native-largelist) it do all the optimization of rendering big items, my problem is when setting the state

Comment: i have also tried the spread operator, sadly it makes no difference.

Comment: just something to think about ... maybe any performant solution of Infinite scrolling might be in need of the least possible abstraction, thus own low-level modeling and own render methods with direct DOM access where one actually is in real control of a browser's rendering.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) creates a new array, copying all values and object references into the new array.. That means, if you have an array with 500 items and you want to add 500 more items, you have to allocate 1000 more items into memory.

You would be better off just adding your new items to the existing array:

`prev.push(...result)`

Comment: If setData comes from the useState hook, OP needs a new array or the hook won't update the component.

Comment: you cant push of React state.

Comment: `.push(...foo)` also can blow the argument stack, if it's big enough (not 500 items, but it's still not a general solution...).